# How can I weight certain factors more heavily when computing distance function?

Tags: r, distance-functions, dendrogram

I'm working on a "player phylogeny" to help make comparisons between potential NBA draft picks and current players. An example is shown below:

[image]

I'm using the dist() function in R, and am assuming that all factors are equally weighted. It's clear to me by looking at the results that some factors need to carry more weight. So my question is pretty simple. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: programmitically ? I mean, do you ask how to this in R ? Or in general ?

Comment: @steffen Yes, how would you do this in R? One thought I have is to normalize all the factors and multiply each by its appropriate weight. But I'm not sure whether dist() already does the normalization. If so, then I would need to override it, I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the docs of *dist*, *daisy* in the package *cluster* is one way to go since it allows to specify column weights (see *help(daisy)*). This is especially useful in the case of purely categorical or mixed variables, meanwhile one can transform purely numerical variables beforehand to achieve the same effect (as long as the distance function is not scale invariant).